# Preview when fold full information when unfold

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworks

I am currently looking for a control that allows me to show only few informations when the control is fold. And when we click on the control, the control is unfold and all the information of the control are showed. I have checked if I could use ListView but I did not see a match and the TreeView does not fit my will because it's not a child node but the same node showed in a different way.

Can you help me find a control that could fit my needs ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into the [Expander](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander(v=vs.110).aspx) control. You can modify the [control template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/248112/Templating-WPF-Expander-Control) to customize how it looks and behaves.